# FHIR: Identifier is missing in some resources

Tags: c#, hl7-fhir

I am trying  to derive all resources from reference(name "Resource" ) class to solve a problem(e.g In group Resource--> **member : Resource(Patient|Practitioner|Device|
Medication|Substance**) 0..*).

I have taken identifier as a data member in reference class and derived all resource from this class using .NET. But problem is here, **identifier is missing** in Resources "Substance and Medication".How to solve this problem ??? please help

Regards

Answer (score 5):

You are confusing an `Identifier` with a `logical ID.`

An `Identifier` is a unique name given to a first class entity by some organisation. It has two major components a `system` and a `value`, where `system` is the organisation and `value` is the unique ID within the organisation.  There can always be multiple identifiers for a first class entity.  For example, a Patient can have a social security number and a passport number (`http:irs.gov|xxx-xx-xxxx` and `http:travel.state.gov|xxxxxxx`).

Not all FHIR resources have identifier, e.g. are not first class entities.

However, all FHIR resources have a `logical ID.`  This is the server assigned ID.  It is usually a `GUID` or some monotonically increasing integer.

I would suggest using @Ewout's C# library (https://github.com/ewoutkramer/fhir-net-api) for dealing with FHIR resource's data model and serialisation/deserialisation. Then you can just concentrate on business problem.

Answer (score 3):

In FHIR we have two identifiers: the *business* identifiers (like a Patient number, order number) etcetera and a infrastructural REST identifier, which looks like http://someserver.org/Patient/3AF334-5 and which identifies a specific instance of a resource on a specific server. You can regard this as the "technical" or "database" key, and those identifiers are generated by the server, maybe by producing incremental numbers.

If you look at the contents of Resources in the specification, they will only show the *business* identifier (if a Resource has one). Of course, every instance of a Resource has a technical id, especially if it is published using REST. This id is not shown on the Resource, as it is considered "metadata", just like the resource's last update date and the login who has created the resource on the server.

If you are doing REST, the Resource's technical id is the URL at which you have retrieved the resource using GET. When you do a POST, you'll receive this id in the Location header. This means you'll have to keep the Resource's data (which is in the body) and the resources REST location together.

One way to do that is to use a class like ResourceEntry (which are Resource + metadata) from the reference implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Identifier is not in the base resource, and so what you are trying to do can't be done, because, as you say, Substance and Medication don't have identifiers.

Comment: If you think they should have identifiers, you are welcome to make a change proposal (see the bottom of every page of the specification)

Comment: Sir. see in Group resource a attribute "member" have so many resources (Patient|Practitioner|Device| Medication|Substance). I want to take one class(Reference class) and derive all other resource from that class. I have taken Class with a name "Resource" having one Data member "Identifier". now this identifier is present in every resource Except Substance and medication. Now how Will I derive these resources from reference class having data member "Identifier"?because substance and medication have no identifier. I think it is must to include identifier in all resources...

Comment: If u have any other idea to solve the problem of attributes having many resources (like in Group resource,  member : Resource(Patient|Practitioner|Device| Medication|Substance)). please Share . Regards

Comment: Have you looked at the Java or DotNet reference implementations? The shared elements are defined in Resource, and the other elements are defined on the relevant resources.

Comment: No, I have not. On this base I have taken Identifier as share element in Resource Class. because Identifier is common in all resources except Substance and medication. I have implemented other Resources it work well.

Comment: Grahame is referring to the dotnet reference implementations, for example found here: https://github.com/ewoutkramer/fhir-net-api